# How do I express double quotes " in Highlight.js

Tags: angular6, highlight.js

I just updated my site to Angular6 but I ran into issues with Prism.js and decided to check out Highlight.js. This seems better suited for Angular6 but how do I express certain characters such as ".

Comment: Are you looking for escape character -> \" ?

Comment: Hey, I've tried \" but it seems to be interpreted as something else and usually breaks the page.

Comment: can you show how you used it in your code?

Comment: Sure, something like this.  <pre><code highlight [code]="print("Cat's") "></code></pre>

Comment: i suggest trying this [code]="print('Cat\'s')", im not positive it works

Comment: Well that does work, but the problem is that I cannot display double quotes " which is different from ' in programming languages like C, C++, and Arduino. Double quotes are usually for strings, while single quotes are for single characters.